# The recording video plays too fast

Tags: java, android, mediamuxer

I made a Live Recording application using by MediaMuxer and MediaCodec.
And Recording format is .mp4. Video and audio is right. Playtime is same (use stopwatch). Video's and audio's sync is same.

My problem is the mp4 file that I record play too fast. I mean the video is like double speed.  I don't know how to solve this problem.

Comment: Are you using MediaCodec in sync or async mode?

Comment: I don't think there is enough information here to help someone diagnose your problem. Would you include some code and some config, using the formatting tools provided? Readers ideally need an [mcve] to help.